# Is it possible to configure the node.js console to be visible in the browser

Tags: node.js

I am a front-end developer.I'm learning node.js now.it's unusual for me to see console in Terminal.Is it possible to configure so that the console is visible in Chrome ?.

Comment: check this out
https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `node inspector` module or if your Node Version is v6.3.0+ you already have this functionallity:

**Using `--inspect` command from Node v6.30.0+ :**

1. Run your JS file with: `node --inspect YOUR_FILE_NAME.js`
2. Go to `about:inspect` in Chrome.
3. Then in "Devices" click on "Open dedicated DevTools for Node"
4. Now you have your Chrome Dev Tools integrated with your Node application.

**Using Node Inspector module:**

1. Install the module globally:
   `$ npm install -g node-inspector`
2. Start the module with: `node-debug YOUR_FILE_NAME.js`

Fonts: [Debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.pmqejrn8q)
[Node Inspector documentation](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)